# How do I patch Minecraft's LWJGL libraries for ARM64 for MultiMC?

Tags: minecraft, arm64

Though this question has been asked before, all information I can found is outdated, so I decided to ask myself.

For those that don't know, MultiMC is a free, open-source launcher for Minecraft. I'm using it because I prefer it to the default launcher, and I found it easier to install, which I did by compiling it myself.

When launching the game, MultiMC copies libraries from common folders, as detailed in the log below. Therefore, information on how to patch a normal Minecraft's install would also be helpful.

Minecraft's default Linux LWJGL library is not built for ARM and thus the game crashes during initialization. At least, I believe that is the problem, though I'm not entirely sure.

[Here is the full log.](https://gist.github.com/eutropius225/803e014a067137cc1012d549a9dd20cb#file-unchanged-lwjgl-3-2-2)

I have tried, using a shell script, simply replacing *all* the .jar files in the `.../install/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-*/3.2.2/` folders, with the equivalent ARM files downloaded from lwjgl.org (which are 3.2.3, if that matters). [That yields this crash.](https://gist.github.com/eutropius225/803e014a067137cc1012d549a9dd20cb#file-changed-lwjgl-3-2-3)

But now I'm at a loss for what to do. Am I even addressing the right problem?

Comment: This [wrapper script](https://github.com/CoolCat467/fix-lwjgl) forces Minecraft to use the right version of LWJGL for your system

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but there is a [MultiMC fork for arm64](https://github.com/JJTech0130/MultiMC5) (on GitHub).

It works for me and I can launch Minecraft on it.

Comment: Can you please expand this to explain how to install it?

Comment: @Zanna Go to the releases page - https://github.com/JJTech0130/MultiMC5/releases - download the latest amd64 package, extract, and run the `MultiMC` executable.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the tip! The fork doesn't seem to be updated for 1.16 yet; but there's been recent development activity so hopefully that's coming soon.